# Find error for Taylor series

Tags: summation, power-series

I posted this task yesterday. I got help with understanding how to solve a part of the problem but the other part still confuses me. The task is:

Use the power series to $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ to find the Taylor series to

$g(x)=\ln(1+2x)$ about $x=0$

I then did this

$$\int\frac{1}{1-x}=\int\sum{x^n}$$
$$-\ln(1-x)=\sum{\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}}$$
$$\ln(1-x)=-\sum{\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}}$$

Then I use substituion and plugg in $-2x$ for $x$ and get

$$\ln(1+2x)=\sum{\frac{(-1)^{n+2}(2x)^{n+1}}{n+1}}$$

So the question remaining is:
How many terms should one have in the estimation of $\ln(1,02)$ for the error to be less than $2\times10^{-6}$?. I don't know where to begin. Should I use the Langrange remainder? I don't understand where to begin. Really appreciate some help.

Comment: Note that the series, evaluated at $x=10^{-2}$, gives you the required value and is alternating. In such a series the absolute value of the next term bounds the error of the partial sum. So, it is sufficient to sum until the next term is smaller than $2\cdot 10^{-6}$.

Comment: For an alternating series $s_n= \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i a_i$ with limit $s$ and monotone decreasing positive $a_n$ the error $|s-s_n|$ can be estimated by $a_{n+1}$. This is a common result about alternating series and should be found in most textbooks. It's also not too difficult to prove and can be done as an exercise, if you don't happen to know it.

Comment: @flan alternating alone is not sufficient

Comment: @flan. So I should just find the term which is less than $2*10^{-6}$ ??

Comment: @Mathomat55 Yes, that is enough.

Comment: I just want to make sure that I'm doing this right. So I plugg in for n using x=0.01 until I find the term that is less than the error allowed

$ln(1+2x)=0,02-\frac{1}{5000}+2.67*10^{-6}-4.0*10^{-8}$ So I need at least 4 terms?

Comment: For an alternating series, the limit is between successive partial sums. So instead of taking the last partial sum and saying the error is bounded by the absolute value of the last term, take the preceding partial sum + 1/2 the last term and the error is bounded by 1/2 the absolute value of the last term.